# Wall mounted dial thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I recently bought a wall thermostat I broke the plastic front on the box to remove
The  thermostat as I tried to pull it out    of the box the dial came off in my hand and I do not know where it should be positioned for the right position for the dial to be put at the right degree on the spline of he thermostat can any one help
Thanks terry.

Comment: This isnt answerable without a picture. Can you add one?  It might not be repairable at all.

Comment: Agreed. It's also not clear what you're asking. If it broke as you pulled it out of the box it was packaged in then take it back and get another one.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a notch, slot, groove, or other marking on the shaft. Which should align with a similar marking on the knob.

If not... Simply turn the shaft to one of the extremes (all the way up or down), then install the knob to indicate the appropriate setting.